# Can I render only meta tags as SSR in my website?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side, server-side-rendering, meta-tags

I have a complete website built with React for frontend and NodeJs + Express for backend. My need is to have dynamic OG (Opengraph) Tags for a specific route, which used by specific component.

Since it will be difficult to me to convert this component to SSR, because it's a dynamic component that also used for another page such as real time component (that changes as the user input) so I don't think it should be rendred with SSR, I came up with idea that I don't know if it's possible, and it's to render only meta tags as SSR.

This is relevant code:

**Frontend - React:**

The route:

```
<Route exact path="/DigitalCard/:cardId" component={DigitalCard} />
```

This is `DigitalCard` Component:

```
export default class DigitalCard extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            card: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      const cardId = this.props.match.params.cardId;
      axios.get(serverApiUrl + '/' + cardId)
         
         // response.data is server's api as json
         .then(response => this.setState({ card: response.data }))
         .catch(...);
    }

    cardFactoryByDesign = (card) => {
        // Create the design of the card, Uses eventually a lot of help components.
    }

    render() {
        let card = this.state.card;
        return (
            <MetaData
               name={card.Name}
               description={card.Name}
               ogUrl={clientUrl + "/" + card.cardId}
               imgUrl={card.CardImage}
            />
            { this.cardFactoryByDesign(card) }
        )
    }
}
```

And this is `MetaData` Component:

```
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import MetaTags from 'react-meta-tags';

export default function MetaData(props) {
    const [meta] = useState({
        name: props.name,
        description: props.description,
        ogUrl: props.ogUrl,
        imgUrl: props.imgUrl
    });

    return (
        <>
            <MetaTags>
                <meta name="title"              content={meta.name}        />
                <meta name="description"        content={meta.description} />
                <meta property="og:title"       content={meta.name}        />
                <meta property="og:image"       content={meta.imgUrl}      />
                <meta property="og:description" content={meta.description} />
                <meta property="og:url"         content={meta.ogUrl}       />
            </MetaTags>
            <Helmet>
                <title>{meta.name}</title>
                <meta name="title"              content={meta.name}        />
                <meta name="description"        content={meta.description} />
                <meta property="og:title"       content={meta.name}        />
                <meta property="og:image"       content={meta.imgUrl}      />
                <meta property="og:description" content={meta.description} />
                <meta property="og:url"         content={meta.ogUrl}       />
            </Helmet>
        </>
    );
}
```

**Backend - Nodejs + Express:**

```
router.get('/:cardId', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let visitCard = await VisitCard.findOne({ _id: req.params.cardId });
    if (visitCard)
      return res.status(200).json(visitCard);
    else 
      ...
    }
  } catch (error) {
      ...
  }
});
```

This is my existing code so far.
Now, I'm asking if I can do something like this in my backend:

```
const pathToIndex = path.join(__dirname, '../views/metaTags.html');
router.get('/getCardMetaTags', (req, res) => {
  const TITLE, DESCRIPTION, IMAGE, URL = ...
  res.send('index', { title: TITLE, description: DESCRIPTION, image: IMAGE, url: URL }); // Not Quite sure if send / render / anything else
})
```

And inside `metaTags.html` write with html the `<head>` section with all of the meta tags, and when I request the API on the client side, I will also send somehow this section.

Is this possible or anyone have better idea? Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it will not be possible to do this without SSR. Simply because Facebook / Twitter / Google crawler will not execute the api call. What you have to remember is that React app in reality have only one route and one html file (the one with `<div id="root"></div>`), the JS takes over and feeds the browser the selected components. Everything happens at the browser / client level, and since crawlers do not execute the JS (only google but not at first crawl, plus you have to add robots.txt, sitemap), they only will see the html template you use for your React app.

That is way you have Gatsby.js (SSG) and Next.js (SSR and SSG) frameworks. React in itself has no SEO support, you may see the metadata loaded in the browser but is dynamically added by JS.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea what shold I do for this to work correctly? Some good explnations and code examples? Also to remember that the ```DigitalCard``` component used in client side in another way, so I shouldn't copy that component to the backend.